# jQuery always has one checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

With the following HTML checkbox code

```
<input type="checkbox" class="example" checked />2016
<input type="checkbox" class="example" />2015
<input type="checkbox" class="example" />2014
<input type="checkbox" class="example" />2013
<input type="checkbox" class="example" />2012
<input type="checkbox" class="example" />2011
<input type="checkbox" class="example" />2010
```

What changes do I need to make to the following jQuery

```
 $(function() { 
     $('input[type="checkbox"]').bind('click',function() {
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop("checked", false);
     });
});
```

so that one of the checkboxes is checked at all times not allowing blank checkboxes?

Comment: Stop using checkboxes, this isn't how they work. Use radio buttons, this is exactly what they're for.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you didn't want to use radio button instead.
This is updated code of yours, it works as desired. You will need to make sure that a checked box will not unchecked by re-clicking.

```js
$(function() { 
     $('input[type="checkbox"]').bind('click',function() {
         if($(this).prop('checked') === false) {
           $(this).prop('checked', true);
         }
         $('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop("checked", false);
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="example" checked />2016
<input type="checkbox" class="example" />2015
<input type="checkbox" class="example" />2014
<input type="checkbox" class="example" />2013
<input type="checkbox" class="example" />2012
<input type="checkbox" class="example" />2011
<input type="checkbox" class="example" />2010
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like You've beautiful UI components with checkboxes, so that's why You don't want to use radio inputs?

About Your question: Your code works as desired

```js
 $(function() { 
     $('input[type="checkbox"]').bind('click',function() {
        $(this)
          .parent()
          .find('[type="checkbox"]').not(this)
          .removeAttr('checked');
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" class="example" checked />2016
<input type="checkbox" class="example" />2015
<input type="checkbox" class="example" />2014
<input type="checkbox" class="example" />2013
<input type="checkbox" class="example" />2012
<input type="checkbox" class="example" />2011
<input type="checkbox" class="example" />2010
```

Comment: This currently allows the checked item to be unchecked when clicked. **$(this).prop('checked', true).parent().find...** will make one stay checked

Comment: @smcd You're not right. Because there is not() function that chained after find selector. Also take look at how it works, click on "run" button.

Comment: I did - 2016 is checked. click that checkbox and it allows it to be unchecked, which OP didn't want to happen.

Comment: @scmd, I don't think so. not() is chained after find() selector. Your way just make every checkboxes become uncheckable.

Comment: @namhd it works https://jsfiddle.net/m46h1ew6/ however neither this code nor my suggested edit to it works in jsfiddle with jquery > 2.2.4 (does with jquery 3.0.0 IF migrate is enabled).

Answer (score 0):

There is yet another (shorter) way of achieving the same:

```
$(function() { 
   $(':checkbox').click(function(){
      $(this).prop('checked', true).siblings(':checkbox').prop("checked", false);
   });
});
```

It will simply always keep the clicked element checked and all siblings unchecked.